# Is QGIS Supported on Windows 8?

Tags: qgis, windows-8

Can QGIS be installed on Windows 8?
I'm going to buy a laptop with Windows 8, but I have no idea if Windows 8 can run QGIS.

Comment: Having QGIS on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (including Pro) they all work, there is a compatibility mode for it if required. The windows 7 version crashes when exiting the application.

Comment: For me, it works on Windows 7 without crashes. There were some bugs in the 1.8.0 standalone installer regarding blanks in path names. They should be fixed in OSGEO4W setup.

Answer (score 1):

I installed it in Dec.2012 on a friend's new desktop with windows 8 and forgot to add plugins. It worked fine to view the shapefiles I wanted but didn't open the .tif files (because of the missing plugins).